# Show invisible Tab characters but not end of line characters in Dreamweaver CS4/5?

Tags: dreamweaver, text-coloring, hidden-characters

A friend of mine uses Coda, another Geany, which both have the ability to only show Tab and Space invisible characters and not end of line characters.

Can anyone enlighten me on a way to do this in Dreamweaver?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dreamweaver has an option to display hidden characters such as spaces and tabs:
View -> Code View Options -> Hidden Characters, however that option also includes the end of line characters. So no, you cannot do what you are asking, you get both in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thank you -> based on that I have decided to change editor.

Comment: It felt awkward to +1 an answer stating there's no solution